# How to convert string to Long (not long) in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, frontend

The backend API implementation is expecting an array of *Long* .

I need to pass the value through front-end which is a GraphQL implementation. Initially I have the value as a string and want to convert it to an array of *Long* so that it is compatible with the API.
I have tried the following:

```
input1 = [JSON.parse(input1)]
```

The desired payload should be as follows where 140 is a "Long"

```
"rolls": [140]
```

I currently see my graphQL query variables as follows where 140 is a string.

```
rolls: 140
```

Currently, I am seeing the GraphQL error:
[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of the actual input and the desired output?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: Sure, Just updated the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @user85421: The code is in TypeScript. So, do you know how I could use "Long.valueOf()" in TypeScript. Thanks!

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I tagged Java to highlight that the API implementation in Java is Long

Answer (score 2):

use `Number` to convert value from string to number

```
const someValueStr = "140";
const someValueNum = Number(someValue);
```

in JavaScript there is number type not long or double or int

Comment: I did try this, but am still seeing the same GraphQL error as I believe it would work if the API implementation expected a primitive data type like int, float, long, etc.

Comment: I am trying to convert it to **Long** which is like an object form of **long**

Comment: @vv1129 it's also a datatype that does not exist in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Typescript (the whole javascript actually) has just one data type for numbers, i.e Number, and they store numbers in 64 bits (or [double-precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

There is a library called [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) which can help you to represent numbers bigger than what javascript supports.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I've had no luck either with Number or BigInt and still seeing the same error that I posted above.